# present perfect to express the future

Tags: present-perfect

August 11, 2020, 12:10 am

Arrival at Post Office

FRANCE

Your item **has arrived** at the delivering post office in FRANCE at 12:10 am on August 11, 2020.

I don't understand the "has arrived"the use of present perfect: does it express the future?. In France, when I read this on my computer it was 8 olock in the morning on August 11. Why not "is going to arrive" or "will arrive"?
I know the day is not finished and the item has not arrived yet at the time of writing this but I find strange to use present perfect for a precise moment in the future

Comment: It looks to me like an error in the automatic messaging system. There is no reason for _has arrived_ to be used for an event in the future.

Answer (score 1):

12:10am is ten minutes after midnight (00h10). You checked your email in the morning at 8am the same day, about eight hours later. So the tense is correct for the situation; I think the misunderstanding came from your thinking that 12:10am Aug 11 is temporally after 8:00am Aug 11.

12am is midnight (00h00). One minute later is 12:01am; one hour later is 1:00am. The "am" counting continues until noon. 11:59am is right before noon, and noon itself is 12pm, followed by 12:01pm and then 1pm (13h00), 2:30pm (14h30) and so on. This continues until 11:59pm (23h59), after which a new day starts at 12am midnight.

The email just said your item arrived at the post office; it did not explicitly say that it was out for delivery, or that it will necessarily be delivered today.

Comment: So why not past simple as the time is precise and belongs to the past or why it is not written just  has just arrived

Comment: According to the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Present_perfect#English) about the present perfect, "The present perfect in English is used chiefly for completed past actions or events when it is understood that it is the present result of the events that is focused upon, rather than the moment of completion." Simply saying "Your item arrived at the post office at 12:10am" is correct in this context as well, but by saying the item "has arrived" gives the sense that the arrival was anticipated and, now that it has happened, allows for further action